# 401 race conditions with axios/laravel - CSRF/Unauthenticated

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, vuejs3

I have a SPA application that is powered via `axios`. Now, I originally noticed that the CRSF token was being dropped randomly which we identified as a race condition when two requests fired concurrently. I since changed the storage mechanism for sessions to the database and added atomic blocking to my routes and disabled the requirement for CSRF for routes that where not "action" routes.

Now, what is interesting, I get a 401 unauthenticated instead (randomly). I found a post online about reattempting to capture all the new session/token so I wrote the following:

```
let retries = [];

const sessionHandler = async error => {
    if (error.response && (error.response.status === 419 || error.response.status === 401)) {
        const uri = error.response.config.url;
        const data = error.response.config.data;

        // I use nothing from this endpoint, its simply to allow
        // axios to get the CSRF token
        const endpoint = '/session/user-config';

        // Push to retries
        retries.push({uri: uri, data: data});

        // After exhausting retries, force refresh
        if (retries.filter(attempt => attempt.uri === uri).length > 3 || retries.filter(attempt => attempt.uri === endpoint).length > 3) {
            window.location.reload();
        }

        // Attempt to obtain new token
        return await axios.get(endpoint).then(async () => {
            // Attempt to fulfill request
            return await axios.post(uri, data).then(response => response);
        });
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
};

window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    // Remove any attempts after a successful request
    retries.filter(attempt => attempt.uri = response.config.url).forEach(attempt => {
        retries.slice(retries.indexOf(attempt), 1);
    });

    return response;
}, sessionHandler);
```

This successfully (70% of the time) grabs a new token should any 419 errors get thrown. Now, for the other 30%, it loops and eventually reloads the page. During this reload, after a 401 Unauthenticated 3 times, it redirects to login.

This can happen **within the first 2 minutes** of logging in sometimes. I have increased the session lifetime to 1 year to debug, I have tried everything locally to reproduce this, as well as on dev/test servers and yet it seems to be only effecting the production server.

I've tried to check all the configuration for differences but none can be found. I cannot find any known issues surrounding this and the 70% is not a solution but more a duck-tape fix. Does any one know if there is something additional I can do to laravel or axios to prevent this issue?

This happens randomly, I can click around really fast for ages and it won't happen, then randomly, it will happen.

Update: I have noticed that every request, made by axios, updates the local cookie value of the session, I'm unsure if this is normal behaviour but potentially it could be encountering a read/write issue? Is it even possible to add blocking to cookies?

When watching the request, both the CSRF and session cookies are sent. The request appears fine but yet it results in either a 419 CSRF token issue or a 401 Unauthenticated. I then resend the request and it works fine - it is totally randomly failing.

Below is an example of what can been seen, one request got a 401 response code but yet all the others worked perfectly fine.

[image: 401]

Sometimes, all of these might 401. Inside the request, the CSRF token and laravel_session is sent in the headers and cookies. No signs of anything missing or dropping out as seen below in the request:

419 Request:

[image: 419]

401 Request:

[image: 401]

Another update, after using the debugger tools, I can see Axios runs into an exception during a 401:

[image: Exception Axios]

The full exception is detailed below but only triggers during a 401:

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

Comment: "every request, made by axios, updates the local cookie value of the session" do you mean a new session ID is sent with every response?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @miken32 a new session ID is sent back with every response and thus updates the cookie - I'm unsure if this is normal behaviour but just trying to isolate what could be causing this

Comment: The value in the cookie is encrypted with a salt so it will always change with each request; I thought you meant the session ID on the server side keeps changing which would be weird.

Comment: My `secure` is set to null, I would of thought that would prevent that but if it isn't the cause of the problem and is normal behaviour, that is better I guess! Actually really appreciate knowing that! I'm unsure if the session ID on the server changes, one would doubt it as I use the database and when monitoring it, it never changes. I sometimes see null in the `user_id` field but its rare. @miken32 The real part I can't undertstand is why the next request works perfectly fine and why the server response has a session in it if it thinks its unauthenticated?

Comment: I remember a similar problem caused by mixing session domains with dot (`.example.com`) and domains without dot (`example.com`).

Comment: Is the race condition because you are loading an async function leveraging axios before requiring axios. So depending on how long that function takes it breaks?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AlexMac, `axios` is required inside the `bootstrap.js` as standard in Laravel prior to any request so I doubt it will be due to it firing early. I'm beginning to believe this may be a load balancer issue, potentially encryption keys being different between each server etc... but I am yet to identify where and why

Comment: I think we can solve this but I do have a few questions:

- How do you handle session storage? Are you using database as session storage? 
- Do you have a single instance handling all requests or do you have a load balancer setup in between? 
- Does the application work as expected when there is no CSRF at all? 
- Have you tweaked the same-site options in config/session.php?

Comment: I handle session storage via the database, I'm using Azure Web App Services so the only thing I know about is the network load balancer, AFAIK, its a single instance server. When disabling the CSRF tokens in the Middleware, I instead recieve a 419 unauthenticated error. I have not yet added the `SESSION_DOMAIN` into the `.env`

Comment: Can you provide some insight into the code that's making these axios requests close together? I have a hunch it is a race condition for the `419` as you have suggested - the second request likely starting before the first request finishes, but after the token has been updated in session. The likely answer to that is to make sure your calls happen sequentially (using `async/await` or doing one in the `then` callback of another)

Comment: You're correct in saying there is no aysnc/await, the issue is, its across the entire app and its a nightmare. However, it isn't causing the issues in any other environment which is the part I can't understand as its making it impossible to reproduce. Prior to the changes, the 419 was a race condition where the XSRF token could be seen dropping from the request. The 401, however, shows the correct sessions and if I resend the request in Burp Suite, it works perfectly fine. @simonhamp

Comment: The api and frontend is running on the same domain/origin, right?
Have you tried adding `{withCredentials: true}` to axios requests?

Which laravel middlewares are applied on the affected route? Are you using sanctum or any other auth provider beside the default one?

Comment: I am using the `auth:web` guard, it happens on any route (randomly). Sometimes, it happens more times than others but overall, it happens 30% of the time @posixpascal

Comment: When you remove that middleware the error vanishes I guess? Can you test that so we can pinpoint the issue?

Also can you monitor your database session table and check if the payload/id/last_activity get modified when the error occurs?

I'll try to reproduce it in the meantime.

Comment: That middleware is persistent across the entire application other than the API which uses passport as the authentication mechanism. The SPA application uses session based authentication via axios. The `auth:web` is required in order to retrieve the current `auth()->user()` - without it, I cannot login/etc.. @posixpascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the original post and comments, it seems like you're using the default Laravel authentication for asynchronous communication with the server. I feel like this is ultimately the root of your issue and you should look into utilizing [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport) since you mentioned it was already installed. (If it isn't already installed, I recommend [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum) over Passport for what you describe here because it's simpler.) There are assumptions made that the server will be controlling the application state when you utilize the default authentication.

You also mention that you have to use the default authentication gateway to retrieve the currently logged in user. This means that either you didn't authenticate against Passport correctly or that you're not setting the OAuth token correctly in your requests. Assuming that everything is done correctly, you can get the user from a Passport based request the same way you would get from the default guard.

I know this likely isn't the answer you're looking for, but based on what you're saying it sounds like you've spent more time fighting against the grain of the default authentication middleware than it would take to implement something more suited to the task.

### The Original Problem

The reason that it is intermittent is, as you guessed, a race condition.

When you make a request to Laravel, there is a varying window of time that you can make another request with the same session information that it will be allowed through. This is because the Session information isn't invalidated and "re-salted" immediately, so the original salted session information is still valid for a short time.

Additionally, since the session info comes from a cookie, if the original request returns before the second request is sent, then the cookie is updated to the new value and sent along as expected and will also work.

Essentially, you're getting a 401 because you had a message "in-flight" as the cookie value was changed. This is likely very similar to what you mention running into with the 419 rejection and XSRF.

You can make this work with the default authentication, but it's going to require changing your requests to behave like a queue and make sure the previous one has returned before firing the next one. This comes with it's own downsides (speed being one) and is likely a heavier lift than implementing Passport or Sanctum with your frontend which is why I recommended that up front.

Comment: When I first encourted this, I isolated a potential race condition and implemented the axios interceptor to account for the low probability of the condition being met but not always does this fix it. I also cannot reproduce this (running the same code) on any other environment. I made a local docker instance, with SSL and an SSL-termination proxy (to mimic Azures network balancers) and then continulously sent requests and not once could I reproduce this. I still believe their is a environmental difference, I'm just struggling to isolate where. Further more (next comment)

Comment: I strongly agree with the session based approach to SPA being a problem regardless (speed etc) and that passport should be used but this is so far beyond gone that it will take a lot of time to fix. Perhaps - needed, I'm just looking - right now - for things that could be beyond the infastructural code issue and more into a root-cause analysis at enivronmental level. Once this question has reached its life-span, I will mark this (since this is a very connical and overlyingly correct agrument) as the answer if there is no further ideas or solutions. I appreciate the time you put into writing it

Comment: Just one on the cookie issue, if I re-send the origional failed request with BurpSuite, it works perfectly fine. Only after spamming the request multiple times does the server eventually give me a 401 and revoke the session. If I do the same locally, or on any other server, it doesn't do this - thus suggesting again that something is different enivronmentally. My experience with Azure is little so I was hoping someone may have encountered such issues when hosting via Azure Web Apps

Comment: Been a crazy couple of days at work, so just now getting back to this. I think you're correct in your assessment of the issue ultimately. I don't think you're going to find a good way around this without using something better tooled for it, or without making your requests effectively synchronous. If you didn't already have Passport running, Sanctum is almost a drop-in replacement so that's unfortunate :(

Comment: Hi @blhylton, thanks again for your answer. As it turns out, and hopefully for future viewers, Azure has a "configuration" built into the Azure App service - as it turns out, no matter how much I was editing my configuration files, it wasn't taking in the `.env` file but instead reading from the config in the portal. I hope this helps future viewers. (it takes 5 mins to take effect, I checked with `php artisan tinker` in a SSH shell)

Comment: @Jaquarh That makes perfect sense, and I didn't even think about that being a possible cause of the sessions being stored incorrectly. AWS/Laravel Vapor does the same thing. Glad to hear that you figured it out ultimately, and that it wasn't the craziness I was worried it was.

Comment: I still think you make a solid point, there is ultimatley still an issue where async calls are being created without waiting for a new token thus making it a race condition, it just appears we're not yet hitting the speeds for it to matter. Its something that needs consideration and time to repair regardless and I apprecicate your help identifiying things around it :D